# SQLite return earliest of similar events

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of events. Some of the events are of a repeating nature, so will share the same name. I need to return results which return the ealiest of each event. I need the  fields as shown in the query below. I can't use group by, because the only thing that is the same is the title. I need all the details of the earliest entry of each event

```
select id, title, event_date, url from events where event_date > date()
```

I have tried a sub query, which would work if I was using MIN(id), but I need the id of the MIN(event_date)

Comment: Some sample data and your desired results would help us answer the question.

Comment: "*I need to return results which return the earliest of each event.*" How do we identify which rows are the same event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some of the events are of a repeating nature, so will share the same name. I need to return results which return the earliest of each event.

I'm going to assume by "name" you mean "title".

First, use [`row_number`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-row_number/) to order each event by date. If there can be multiple events with the same date, and you want to show all of them, use [`rank`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-rank/) instead.

Then query only those with a row number / rank of 1.

```
with events_ordered as (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (
      partition by title
      order by event_date desc
    ) as date_order
  from events
)
select id, title, event_date, url
from events_ordered
where date_order = 1;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/tkY_fkwR).